# How to adjust video size magnific popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I am trying to adjust the video to smaller center, currently right now it is zooming on the entire monitor, i believe these are some custom css adjustments?

scroll down to Investing Where It Matters Most and click on the picture.
http://www.cyberjunkiesinteractive.com/ocdc/

This is the relevant code:

```
<div class="col-md-video">
    <a class="popup-youtube" href="vimeo.com/113750801">; <span class="video" id="video1">&nbsp;</span> </a>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({ disableOn: 700, type: 'iframe', mainClass: 'mfp-fade', removalDelay: 160, preloader: false, fixedContentPos: false }); }); </script>
```

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: <div class="col-md-video">
                <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://vimeo.com/113750801">
                  <span class="video" id="video1">&nbsp;</span>
                </a><script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   
  
  
  $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
          disableOn: 700,
          type: 'iframe',
          mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
          removalDelay: 160,
          preloader: false,

          fixedContentPos: false
        });
  
  
 }); 
</script>